# How to hide only one mapping from swagger ui documentation if I more than one mapping for method in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I've one spring boot rest controller method which is mapped to multiple mappings. Please find the example code below.

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping( {"/", "/home"} )
    public String home() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }

}
```

I want to hide `/home` mapping from swagger documentation.

Can someone please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also searched for a way to hide certain URLs from multi mapping methods. Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible when multi mapping it's defined like this  `@RequestMapping( {url1, url2} )`

There are 2 alternative ways to do it:

1. Split your method into 2 methods that call the same function and annotate the one you want to hide with @Operation(hidden=true)
2. Define exceptions in your swagger config (for swagger 3 which uses open API):

   ```
    @Configuration
    public class SwaggerConfig {

        @Bean
        public GroupedOpenApi myApi()
        {
            return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .pathsToMatch("/**")
                .pathsToExclude("/home")
                .build();
        }
    }
   ```